# Create cascading dropdown in Modern SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, cascading, cascading-dropdown

We have three lists in modern SharePoint:

1. Company:

[image]

2. Employee: Used lookup on Industry column

[image]

3. Database: Used lookup on Employee and Industry column

[image]

**Question**: How can I show only those employees which are belonged to specific company while adding new item in Database? Example: If I select **CTS** as company then only **A** employee should be visible in Employee column dropdown.

As per current lookup, all the employees are visible in all the companies while adding new item.
[image]

**Note**: Modern SharePoint does not support any external scripting file.

Comment: Can you use PowerApps? If so check this [link](https://www.techmikael.com/2019/01/a-no-nonsense-solution-to-implement.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a cascading dropdown in modern experience, you will need to use PowerApps like Sandro said.

For classic experience, you can [insert a java script](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/cascading-of-lookup-dropdown-fields-on-sharepoint-2013-and-o/) to get it done or use InfoPath (not recommended).